# LINQ to SQL - Left OUTER Join with two joins not working

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015

In the following LINQ Query I need to display `All` the customers including the customers that have not placed any order but whose order is priced more than $100. But my following LINQ Query is returning all the customers regardless of their order price. It seems to be ignoring my `Where(ord => ord.price > 100)` clause in the LINQ query below. What I may be doing wrong?

**Models**:

```
public class Customer
{
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string CustName{ get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public float price  { get; set; }
}
```

**LINQ Query**:

```
var Query1 = from c in Customers
             join ord in Orders on c.CustomerId equals ord.CustomerId into cord into cord
             from t in cord.Where(ord => ord.price > 100).DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {CustName= c.Name, OrderID = (t == null ? 0 : t.OrderId)};
```

**SQL Query**:

I want to translate following T-SQL query into LINQ query:

```
SELECT c.Name, OrderID
FROM Customers c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ord
    ON c.CustomerID = ord.CustomerID
    AND ord.Price > 100
```

Comment: So you want to return a list of all customers, with the `OrderId` only populated with an order that was over 100? Or do you want to return a list of the customers that have placed an order over 100?

Comment: @WillRay Thank you for trying to help. I've added an `UPDATE 2` section in my post to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't have your data to be able to verify this, but one issue that jumps out at me is you're not specifying the field (CustomerId) on which to join the two collections.

Try modifying your query like this: (adding `on c.CustomerId equals ord.CustomerId`)

```
var Query1 = from c in Customers
             join ord in Orders on c.CustomerId equals ord.CustomerId into cord
               from t in cord.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where t.price > 100
             select new {CustName = c.Name, OrderID = (t == null ? 0 : t.OrderId)};
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo. I've corrected that but   showing all the customers regardless of price of their order.

Comment: @ GrantWinney Yes, the query output took me to a surprise too.

Comment: Your last comment above worked. So you may want to change your solution with `where t.price > 100` and I'll mark that as an answer.